# Django should log into gunicorn's logfile

Tags: python, django, logging, gunicorn

I've got a django-app which runs on a server. It starts with the gunicorn. I want that django put it's log output into the logfile of gunicorn. But when I look into the file there is no django-log-entry.

I thought when I print the log on the console, gunicorn would log it.

Here is a code-snippet from the starting of the gunicorn:

```
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${django_app_name}.wsgi:application \
        -D \
        -p $unicorn_pidfile \
        -b unix:$unicorn_sockfile \
        --log-level debug \
        --log-file $unicorn_logfile \
        --error-logfile $unicorn_error_logfile \
       # --log-level debug \
       # --log-level debug --log-file $unicorn_logfile \
        #--log-level error --log-file $unicorn_error_logfile \
         -w $num_workers \
        --name $django_app_name > $unicorn_logfile
```

And here is how I (try) to log in django (settings.py):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "[ThreadID: %(thread)d %(asctime)s.%(msecs)d] %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'rest': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Set `--enable-stdio-inheritance` to `True`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added this line but it changed nothing

Comment: I added your line but when I restart my app (with gunicorn) it tells me that enable_stdio_inheritance is false (in the log file). Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

```
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${django_app_name}.wsgi:application \
            -D \
            -p $unicorn_pidfile \
            -b unix:$unicorn_sockfile \
            --log-level debug \
            --log-file $unicorn_logfile \
            --error-logfile $unicorn_error_logfile \
           # --log-level debug \
           # --log-level debug --log-file $unicorn_logfile \
            #--log-level error --log-file $unicorn_error_logfile \
             -w $num_workers \
            --name $django_app_name
```

Just remove `> $unicorn_logfile` at the end of the script . 
`--log-file $unicorn_logfile` is enough for logging.  But you are overriding existing logs by `>` operator